# How to calculate the number of group using R?

Tags: r, data.table

It could be a very easy question, I have a data.table with key and more than 1000 rows, two of which could be set as key. I want to calculate the number of the groups for this dataset.

For example, the simple data is(ID and Act is key)

```
ID  ValueDate Act Volume
1 2015-01-01 EUR     21
1 2015-02-01 EUR     22
1 2015-01-01 MAD     12
1 2015-02-01 MAD     11
2 2015-01-01 EUR      5
2 2015-02-01 EUR      7
3 2015-01-01 EUR      4
3 2015-02-01 EUR      2
3 2015-03-01 EUR      6
```

Here is a code to generate test data:

```
dd <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 ValueDate = c("2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-01-    01","2015-02-01", "2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-03-01"),
                 Act = c("EUR","EUR","MAD","MAD","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR"),
                 Volume=c(21,22,12,11,5,7,4,2,6))
```

in this case, we can see that there are a total of **4** subsets.

I tried to set the key for this table as first,

```
setkey(dd, ID, Act)
```

Then I thought the function of **count** could be working to count the groups. 
Is it right to use the function of  **count**, or there could be a simple method?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nrow(dd[, .(cnt= sum(.N)), by= c("ID", "Act")])

# or using base R
{t <- table(interaction(dd$ID, dd$Act)); length(t[t>0])}

# or for the counts:
dd[, .(cnt= sum(.N)), by= c("ID", "Act")]
   ID Act cnt
1:  1 EUR   2
2:  1 MAD   2
3:  2 EUR   2
4:  3 EUR   3
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way should be `uniqueN`.

```
library(data.table)
dd <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 ValueDate = c("2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-01-01","2015-02-01", "2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-03-01"),
                 Act = c("EUR","EUR","MAD","MAD","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR"),
                 Volume=c(21,22,12,11,5,7,4,2,6))
uniqueN(dd, by = c("ID", "Act"))
#[1] 4
```

Comment: "Fastest" is underselling it; this is simply the correct way.